# Add matrices in a boolean way

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I have some matrices that represent the segmented parts of a picture.
I need to "Add" the segments up to make the segmented picture.

A simpler explanation can be made with arrays.

```
a = [3, 0, 0, 0]
b = [3, 1, 0, 0]
c = [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

how can I make something like:

```
result = a AND b AND c 
result = [3, 1, 0, 1]
```

This is some sort of superposition.

The pixel values are consistent with the position since they come from the same source picture.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the first element 3 or 6? Because you've got 3 + 3 + 0 = 6. If not, can you please explain how this addition is meant to work in more detail.

Comment: That's is the thing! I want to make a superposition not a sum, so what I want is to make 3 & 3 & 0 = 3, the zeros should be ommied some way...I know that 1 & 0 = 0 ...

Comment: 3 and 3 and 0 is 0 though. `3 and 3 and 0 # 0`

Comment: Take the & in a figurative way not strictly boolean, I know that.

Comment: 3 & 3 & 0 is still 0.

Comment: So, how would you say this?

Comment: I don't know, **it's your question.** You need to define *mathematically* what result you want. For instance what if you were doing `4 & 2 & 1`?

Comment: As to my knowledge there is no math symbol for what I want. I need that the pixels are replaced, not added. And I also need that a zeros do not replace a value. I was hoping that there was some numpy function for this.

Comment: Right, so do you want the non-zero maximum for each "column"?

Comment: +1 seems ok to me. voted to reopen it again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no library function to do this, so, for those that really understand the question, here is the answer:

```
def non_Destructive_pixel_addition(original, segmentated):

    to_be_added = np.matrix(np.where(segmentated)).transpose()

    n, m = np.shape(to_be_added)

    for k in range(n):
        i = to_be_added[k, 0]
        j = to_be_added[k, 1]
        if (original[i,j] == 0):
            original[i,j] = segmentated[i,j]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no library function to do this, but you can still use numpy functions to help in the calculation. `np.nonzero` will return the indices of all elements that are non-zero, in your case you simply want the last one of these so you can use `np.max` to find it.

Below are two functions which do this, though you have to take care if all elements are 0. One of the functions is spaced out and written for readability (`func`) and one is a one-line list comprehension because LCs are just *awesome.*

```
import numpy as np

a = [3, 0, 0, 0]
b = [3, 1, 0, 0]
c = [0, 0, 0, 1]

data = np.array([a, b, c])

def func_LC(x):
    return np.array([row[np.max(np.nonzero(row))] if len(np.nonzero(row)[0]) else 0 for row in np.array(list(zip(*x)))])

def func(x):
    result = []
    for row in x:
        nonzero = np.nonzero(row)
        if len(nonzero[0]) == 0: # Handles if all elements are 0.
            result.append(0)
        else:
            result.append(row[np.max(nonzero)])
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use list comprehension:

```
result = [a[i] | b[i] | c[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Edit:

For the max value if values can be differents:

```
result = [max(a[i], b[i], c[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: would this work for numpy matrices?

Comment: @user3020849 Sorry, but I don't know numpy…

Comment: Incidentally if you're using numpy, say it in your question as you've shown 3 lists.

Comment: read the question first

Comment: I have read the question, nowhere does it say numpy and it's not tagged as numpy. Also `a = [3, 0, 0, 0]` **this is a list, not a numpy array.**

Comment: Indeed, @user3020849, Fffffffisegydd is right on this one, absolutely no idea based on the question that this would be numpy.